# Android Room - SELECT query using LiveData

Tags: android

I cannot get the ID of my row using the category and date column. Whenever I use the LiveData observe method to update my `int id`, the observe method is carried out last.

E.g. code:

```
if(duplicate) {
    Log.e("FIRST: ", "ID: " + id);
    mViewModel.getId(category, date).observe(getActivity(), new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {
        id = integer;
        Log.e("SECOND", "ID " + id);
        }
    });
    Log.e("THIRD: ", "ID: " + id);
}
Log.v("LOG: ", "ID: " + id);
```

And this are the results from Logcat:

FIRST: ID: 0

THIRD: ID: 0

LOG:: ID: 0

SECOND: ID 1

Why does the code in `mViewModel.getId(category, date).observe...` get carried out after `Log.v`? And how do I make the id in THIRD and LOG to be set as the same as SECOND (aka 1)?

My code in my ViewModel:

```
LiveData<Integer> getId(String cat, String date) {return mRepository.getId(cat, date); }
```

My code in my repository:

```
LiveData<Integer> getId(String cat, String date) {return mBudgetDao.getId(cat, date); }
```

My code in my Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT id FROM budget_table WHERE category = :category AND date = :date")
LiveData<Integer> getId(String category, String date);
```

Is there any other methods to get ID using query, without using `allowMainThreadQueries()` in my database?

Answer (score 0):

When you observe the `LiveData` object in your `mViewModel` it doesn't mean the `onChanged` is going to return straight away. If the `LiveData` object already had a value then you may get it straight away but it's not guaranteed.

What you are essentially doing is observing changes which could happen at any point. In your case, it's a database request that takes some time to complete before returning the value.

Comment: is there any method that I can use to get back the request (the id in my case) before I use the value?

Comment: Unfortunately, without adding the `allowMainThreadQueries`, you must access the database asynchronously even if you were to use another asynchronous method such as kotlin coroutines or `RxJava` `Single`s or `Maybe`s. Why do you have to have it back synchronously? Perhaps your use case can be modified to fit in this asynchronous pattern

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I need to retrieve the id so that I can update the columns in that row. I'm checking if there are any duplicates in the 'category' and 'date' row. If there are duplicates, then use the id to update the other columns in the row, instead of adding a new row. I've been searching for a solution for a couple of days but no luck.

Comment: Look into `Transformations` which allow you to chain LiveData objects together. You could also only fire the next dependent part when the `onChanged` method of a previous observable is called. For `Room` access I personally use RxJava because I am familiar with it and it allows chains like these

Answer (score 0):

LiveData works asynchronously.
If you want synchronous results (executed sequentially) you can't use LiveData.
You can use allowMainThreadQueries() when building database like

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context, AppDatabase::class.java, DATABASE_NAME).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
```

**But this is not recommended at all.** 
The process of selecting data will block the main thread.
You should give some time to read the LiveData documentations and how asynchronous works.

Comment: Is there a recommended way to get back synchronous results without using the `allowMainThreadQueries()` method?

Comment: Not that i know of. And it's meant to be asynchronous so it's best to understand how to use Room with LiveData or RxJava.

Execute all things you need inside the onChanged and that should solve your problem for now. 

It looks like you're new to this. I recommend you to read on how Async and Callbacks work